# How to replace a given string in a bibliography with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, strings, emphasis

Mendeley allows you to emphasise Latin names in article or report titles using HTML notation like so:

```html
A treatise on the ecology of <I>Rattus rattus</I>
```

Using `biblatex`, the tags are passed on "verbatim" and of course LaTeX doesn't understand them. I would like to replace all `<I>` with `\emph{` and all `</I>` with `}`.

I have tried using `\DeclareSourceMap` as follows:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{ 
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
           \step[fieldsource=title, match={<I>}, replace={\emph{}]
            \step[fieldsource=title,match={</I>},replace={}}]
          }
    }      
}
```

But of course LaTeX chokes as the extra `{` and `}` confuse it.

How should I escape the braces for this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that the problem was more with getting Biber to accept what look like XML tags than it was with dealing with the `\emph`, which can be done by wrapping them in a `\regexp`, with escapes. In the end I resorted to specifying the < and > by character number.

Anyway, this seems to work.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{ 
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
           \step[fieldsource=title,
                 match=\regexp{\x3cI\x3e},
                 replace=\regexp{\\emph\{}]
           \step[fieldsource=title,
                 match=\regexp{\x3c/I\x3e},
                 replace=\regexp{\}}]
          }
    }      
}
```

Of course, as any fule kno, parsing HTML with regular expressions is not guaranteed to be robust.

Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ratty,
  author = {Mouse, Michael},
  title  = {A Treatise on <I>rattus rattus</I>},
  publisher = {Rodent Publishers},
  date = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareSourcemap{ 
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
           \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{\x3cI\x3e}, replace=\regexp{\\emph\{}]
           \step[fieldsource=title, match=\regexp{\x3c/I\x3e}, replace=\regexp{\}}]
          }
    }      
}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]