# biblatex: string manipulation after processing of bibtex @STRING

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, strings

I am using biblatex 3.1 in conjunction with some BibTeX (`.bib`) files.  These files begin with `@STRING` macros like

```
@STRING{CUP="Cambridge University Press"}
```

and contain entries that have this form:

```
@BOOK{example,
  AUTHOR       = {John Doe},
  TITLE        = {Leviathan},
  YEAR         = {1992},
  PUBLISHER    = CUP,
  ADDRESS      = {New York},
}
```

Under ordinary use of biblatex, the "CUP" in the publisher field for this entry will be expanded to "Cambridge University Press."  I want it to instead be expanded to "Cambridge Univ Press."

I could make this change just by tweaking the `@STRING` macro in the `.bib` file.  But that would make the change for every biblatex style, and I want to make this change for just one particular biblatex style.  How can I do this?

[How to replace a given string in a bibliography with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83943/how-to-replace-a-given-string-in-a-bibliography-with-biblatex) shows that it's easy to use `\DeclareSourceMap` to do arbitrary search–and–replace on bibliography fields when using a particular biblatex style.  One need only add the relevant `\DeclareSourceMap` command to one's biblatex style (.bbx) file.  The catch is that these commands don't seem to operate on entries like the PUBLISHER field in the example above.  (I don't know why.)

Comment: a different solution would be to store the bibtex records and abbreviations in different bibtex file, and to have multiple abbreviation files (for example, one  with the full expansion and a second with abbreviated expansions). Then you load the needed files.

Comment: @Guido -- Note: I think your comment is a possible solution, and in a way I prefer it to the answer you gave, but there is a "load order" issue with separate @premable files. Generally, the last (re-)definition prevails, but an entry will always (I think) use the @string of its own `.bib` file ... even if the string is redefined later. Thus the different preamble files need to be handled carefully and the @strings should be rigorously kept separate from the `.bib` with the actual entries.... (+1 on the answer, by the way.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\DeclareSourceMap` should use the value of the string given in `@STRING` not the abbreviation.

Thus the definition of `\DeclareSourceMap` should look like:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{ 
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
           \step[fieldsource=publisher, match={Cambridge University Press}, replace={Cambridge Univ Press}]
          }
    }      
}
```

which then produce[image]

Comment: Thank you -- this solution works very nicely.  I though that I'd tested it before posting my question, but I must have screwed up the test.